# Xamarin AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo Timeout

Tags: android, xamarin.forms, timeout

I'm working on a Xamarin.Form App (Android and iOs) which need to get AAID and IDFA.

I started with Android part, I implemented AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo but this function return Timeout error (about after 10s)

I use DependencyService from Form to get AAID from Android project and I compile with Android 11.0
I followed internet examples to achieve it but I'm quite sure I missed something or did something wrong, but what?

What I did :

- Added nuget Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Ads (120.3.0.3) and Xamarin.GooglePlayServices.Basement (117.6.0.4), should be latest compliant with Android 11
- Created Interface for dependency service and Created cs in Android project
- In Form I call my Dependencyservice function using Task.Run to run i in background (not sure it's the rigth way, but function run, otherwise function raise an error)

```
            IDeviceAdIdentifier service = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceAdIdentifier>();
            
            var tadid = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var t = service.GetAdvertisingIdentifier();
                t.Wait();
                return t.Result;
            });

            tadid.Wait();
            Idfa = tadid.Result;
```

- In Android I save Context from MainActivity
- In Android Service I have :

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TestAdId.Droid.Services.DeviceAdIdentifier))]
namespace TestAdId.Droid.Services
{
    public class DeviceAdIdentifier : TestAdId.Services.IDeviceAdIdentifier
    {
        public async  Task<string> GetAdvertisingIdentifier()
        {
            if (MainActivity.Context == null) return "";
            string id = "";
            try
            {
                AdvertisingIdClient.SetShouldSkipGmsCoreVersionCheck(true);
                var adinfo = AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo(MainActivity.Instance); // Also tested with MainActivity.Context which is Application context saved during init
                if (adinfo != null)
                    return adinfo.Id;
            }
            catch (IOException ioerr)
            {
                return ioerr.Message;
            }
            catch (Exception err)
            {
                return err.Message;
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

- In my manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.testadid" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="25" android:targetSdkVersion="30" />
    <application android:label="TestAdId.Android" android:theme="@style/MainTheme" android:icon="@drawable/xamarin_logo">
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AD_MANAGER_APP" android:value="true" />
        <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
        
    </application>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

- The error raised on my Samsung Galaxy A71 is :

  **Message** : java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection

  **StackTrace** :

```
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniStaticMethods.InvokeObjectMethod (System.String encodedMember, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x00018] in <1921523bc22e407fa9a0855bdae29335>:0 
  at Google.Ads.Identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.GetAdvertisingIdInfo (Android.Content.Context context) [0x00027] in /Users/runner/work/1/s/generated/com.google.android.gms.play-services-ads-identifier/obj/Release/monoandroid90/generated/src/Google.Ads.Identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.cs:171 
  at TestAdId.Droid.Services.DeviceAdIdentifier.GetAdvertisingIdentifier () [0x00032] in C:\Working\Digital\Sources\TestAdId\TestAdId\TestAdId.Android\Services\DeviceAdIdentifier.cs:30 
  --- End of managed Java.IO.IOException stack trace ---
java.io.IOException: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.0.1:16)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.getAdvertisingIdInfo(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.0.1:3)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for the service connection
    at com.google.android.gms.common.BlockingServiceConnection.getServiceWithTimeout(com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement@@17.6.0:4)
    at com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient.zzb(com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-identifier@@17.0.1:14)
    ... 1 more
```

I tested an application to retrieve AAID and it works on my phone.

So if someone can help me it will be great. Tell me if you need more information/code

Thanks

Hervé

Comment: Can you provide more code sinppet about MainActivity xml ? I can test on my side. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's just a POC so nothing really special in MainActivity. I created a standard xamarin.Forms project and put my code in about page in a button

Android MainActivity.cs

```
using System;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;

namespace TestAdId.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "TestAdId", Icon = "@mipmap/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation | ConfigChanges.UiMode | ConfigChanges.ScreenLayout | ConfigChanges.SmallestScreenSize )]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        public static Context Context =null;
        public static MainActivity Instance = null;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            Instance = this;
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);


            Context = Android.App.Application.Context;
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
}
```

The About Screen xaml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="TestAdId.Views.AboutPage"
             xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:TestAdId.ViewModels"
             Title="{Binding Title}">
    
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <vm:AboutViewModel />
    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    
    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Color x:Key="Accent">#96d1ff</Color>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ContentPage.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackLayout BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Accent}" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="Fill">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center">
                <ContentView Padding="0,40,0,40" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Image Source="xamarin_logo.png" VerticalOptions="Center" HeightRequest="64" />
                </ContentView>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
        <ScrollView Grid.Row="1">
            <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="30,24,30,24" Spacing="10">
                <Label Text="Start developing now" FontSize="Title"/>
                <Label Text="Make changes to your XAML file and save to see your UI update in the running app with XAML Hot Reload. Give it a try!" FontSize="16" Padding="0,0,0,0"/>
                <Label FontSize="16" Padding="0,24,0,0">
                    <Label.FormattedText>
                        <FormattedString>
                            <FormattedString.Spans>
                                <Span Text="Learn more at "/>
                                <Span Text="https://aka.ms/xamarin-quickstart" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                            </FormattedString.Spans>
                        </FormattedString>
                    </Label.FormattedText>
                </Label>
                <Label x:Name="IdfaLabel" Text="Unknown" TextColor="Black" FontSize="16" ></Label>
                <Button Margin="0,10,0,0" Text="Get IDFA"
                        Clicked="Button_Clicked"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource Primary}"
                        TextColor="White" />
            </StackLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

The About Form Code

````
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TestAdId.Services;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Xaml;
using System.Net;
namespace TestAdId.Views
{
    public partial class AboutPage : ContentPage
    {
        public string Idfa = "";
        public AboutPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            IdfaLabel.Text = "Getting IDFA...";
            IDeviceAdIdentifier service = DependencyService.Get<IDeviceAdIdentifier>();
            
            var tadid = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                var t = service.GetAdvertisingIdentifier();
                t.Wait();
                return t.Result;
            });

            tadid.Wait();
            Idfa = tadid.Result;
            IdfaLabel.Text = Idfa;
        }
    }
}```

Tell me if you need another thing. This is a really simple sample just to try to making AAID working

Thanks

Regards

Hervé
````

Comment: Hi All, Anyone have an idea why I can't get AddId?